# How to trace the queue managers and objects in WebSphere MQ

Tags: ibm-mq

how to trace queue managers and objects in WebSphere MQ

what are the commands to trace the Objects

Answer (score 0):

You don't MQ objects but rather applications.  Did you look up the MQ trace command strmqtrc?  See [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q083660_.htm)